# okhttp browser fingerprint replacement

Tags: java, browser, okhttp

[There is](https://fingerprintjs.com/demo/) a hash on the site found here. This is your fingerprint. I couldn't find how to change this fingerprint,

Here are the ways I tried;

I changed User Agent, I changed IP, but still the hash did not change in any way. On the other hand, if I log in from a different browser, it changes. How does FingerprintJS understand me in okhttp request?

PS: From my experiments, I guess the IP doesn't matter at all for fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with using the browser developer tools like [image: Copy as Curl]

Try that from the command line.  That should show you the headers you have to send and can change.

The site shows that they use TLS details, which probably means that the TLS Version, Ciphers, and other implementation details are also relevant.  You could try to change the default Ciphers to see if that changes it.

Comment: Even though I tried this, the same key is coming.

Comment: What did you change? Ciphers? 
Anyway, I guess they don't want you to do this so probably factor in common attempts to change things?

Comment: headers, this is what I changed but nothing happens. Requests always return the same key.